# App crashes when using locationManager.requestLocation()

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have this code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func sendLocation() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let coordinate = locations.last?.coordinate else { return }
        print(String(coordinate.latitude))
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

When clinking on the `UIButton`, the `IBAction` gets called and the current users location is shown in the console.

Since I need to get the location only once, I would like to use `locationManager.requestLocation()`.

But when removing `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` and replacing `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` with `locationManager.requestLocation()`, the app crashes when pressing the `UIButton` with following logs in the console:

> 2019-01-09 15:48:36.585518+0100 GetLocation[1206:248754] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[CLLocationManager requestLocation],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreLocationFramework/CoreLocation-2245.8.25/Framework/CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.m:897
>
> 2019-01-09 15:48:36.586443+0100 GetLocation[1206:248754] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate must respond to
>   locationManager:didFailWithError:'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x1b4e08ec4 0x1b3fd9a50 0x1b4d1eb3c 0x1b580d1d0 0x1bbcd8280
>   0x104690028 0x10469005c 0x1e20f23f8 0x1e1b7ffb8 0x1e1b802d8
>   0x1e1b7f2d8 0x1e212bb50 0x1e212cdb4 0x1e210c0b0 0x1e21daf1c
>   0x1e21dd914 0x1e21d6404 0x1b4d991f0 0x1b4d99170 0x1b4d98a54
>   0x1b4d93920 0x1b4d931f0 0x1b700c584 0x1e20f0ce4 0x104691564
>   0x1b4852bb4)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException
>
> (lldb)

Why that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You testing this in the simulator?

Comment: @Scriptable No, I don't. I'm testing on a real device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to implement

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
         didFailWithError error: Error) {  --- }
```

Delegate method of [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423786-locationmanager)

Comment: This prevents crashing but the location is also not shown in the console. Any idea why?

Comment: call `sendLocation` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yes, I call `func sendLocation()` by clicking an `UIButton`.

Comment: also `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`

Comment: Wait, I'll rewrite my question …

Comment: I implemented `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {}` now and it's not crashing any more. `locationManager.requestLocation()` seems to work but there is a delay of 10 seconds between pressing the `UIButton` and the location shown up in the console. Any idea why?

Comment: the process isn't synchronous , there should be some dealy according to gps see here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation

Comment: you may change `desiredAccuracy`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear. You need to implement the other delegate method, `locationManager(_:, didFailWithError:)`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func sendLocation() {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let coordinate = locations.last?.coordinate else { return }
        print(String(coordinate.latitude))
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // handle the error
    }
}
```

Comment: This prevents crashing but the location is also not shown in the console. Any idea why?

Comment: @David because the location update doesn't succeed and `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)` is getting called, but you're not displaying or handling the error. This is why you had the crash as well, the `didFailWithError` function was getting called, but it wasn't implemented

Comment: I implemented `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {}` now and it's not crashing any more. `locationManager.requestLocation()` seems to work but there is a delay of 10 seconds between pressing the `UIButton` and the location shown up in the console. Any idea why?

Comment: @David as I've already explained on your other question, location updates are received asynchronously (meaning that there is a delay), due to the fact that the GPS cannot get your location updated instantaneously

Comment: I unterstand this now. But why is `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` working immediately?

Comment: @David it definitely isn't working immediately. It's just the fact the you were calling it several times, so on the 2nd try, it displayed the previously retrieved (and delayed) value

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clearly described.

> reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:'

You must implement

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

}
```

As the requesting location takes place asynchronously, it will take time.
When the location is with Location Manger, it notify user via `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`